# Building Bitcoin from Source on MAC OSX 10.9

Tags: bitcoind, installation

so I'm trying to get bitcoind running on my Mac and I cloned the source code from github. What I tried doing:

```
brew install autoconf automake berkeley-db4 boost miniupnpc openssl pkg-config protobuf qt libtool
git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
make
```

But then I get an error:

```
***No targets specified and no makefile found.
```

However, I'm looking and I see `Makefile.am` Any Ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the file [`doc/build-osx.md`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md), before running `make`, you first need to run `./autogen.sh` and `./configure`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I got the make running however I'm getting a fatal error 'boost/config.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/config.hpp>

Comment: Ask a new question.